# Default value of a list as an argument to a function is not respected after several calls to the function itself

Tags: python

I have encountered a strange behaviour when I define as argument of a function a list, either empty or with default value. Here is an example.

```
def f(my_list=[]):
    my_list.append(1)
    return my_list
```

The first call to the function gives the expected value: [1]. However, if you call it consecutively without redefining that argument explicitly you get the following:

In:

```
for _ in range(7):
    print(f())
```

Out:

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

Python passes lists by reference in the function argument. That means, when you tell `f` to append to `my_list`, it's referring to the same list every time.

If you want a fresh empty list each time, then you should tell python to make a copy, like so

```
def f(my_list=[]):
   result = my_list.copy()
   result.append(1)
   return result
```

Answer (score 1):

Default values are not constructed each time the function is called. Therefore, it's appending to the same list every time